# Usage of the JedisPoolConfig parameter *blockWhenExhausted*

Tags: java, redis, apache-commons, jedis, spring-data-redis

So I have a project where I'm using the `Spring-Data-Redis` to cache some data. The `Spring-Data-Redis` is setup with Jedis using Bean Configuration.

I looked for the `JedisPoolConfig` parameters that can be modified to control the behavior of my Caching and App.

I will like to know the use of the property, `blockWhenExhausted`, which is part of the configurable properties.
The default value is said to be `true`, what behaviour will this default value invoke?
If the value is changed to `false`, what behaviour will this bring it?

Answer (score 5):

The value changes the behavior of [GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(long borrowMaxWaitMillis)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/apidocs/org/apache/commons/pool2/impl/GenericObjectPool.html#borrowObject-long-)

> Borrow an object from the pool using the specific waiting time which only applies if BaseGenericObjectPool.getBlockWhenExhausted() is true.

Which means when you set `blockWhenExhausted` to `false` the time specified with `borrowMaxWaitMillis` will not be used and the `borrowObject` call will block until there is an idle jedis connection from the pool available.

> If the pool is exhausted (no available idle instances and no capacity to create new ones), this method will either block (if BaseGenericObjectPool.getBlockWhenExhausted() is true) or throw a NoSuchElementException (if BaseGenericObjectPool.getBlockWhenExhausted() is false)

**But** interestingly I could not see that the `JedisPool` implementation is actually using the `borrowObject(long borrowMaxWaitMillis)` method.
I could only see that `borrowObject` (without parameter) is called during [getResource (in the version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT)](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/blob/b145a83478194f4be3cd26fb0fe40caedf9255d4/src/main/java/redis/clients/util/Pool.java#L47) . So i'm not sure if the described behavior also applies for JedisPool.

Comment: The method without the parameter is implemented as:
public T borrowObject() throws Exception {
        return borrowObject(getMaxWaitDuration());
    }